# Sort and display data save in sqlite according to date through recyclerview

Tags: java, android

My app is a to-do list app. I'm trying to sort my data in recyclerview according to the date that has been saved into the sqlite database and array list. I've seen people saying that i could use a comparator to do it but I'm not sure how as the date saved into my database is not a string, but each part, the day, month and year and saved as integer separately and then merged into string before display. Also, most sorting solutions done through comparator shown are static data and not from data from the database so I'm not sure how to do it.

Cursor code:

```
        db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from taskRecord", null);
        if(cursor.getCount()>0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                task=cursor.getString(1);
                description=cursor.getString(2);
                day=cursor.getInt(3);
                month=cursor.getInt(4);
                year=cursor.getInt(5);
                hour=cursor.getInt(6);
                minute=cursor.getInt(7);

                taskRecord.add(new MyRecord(task, description, day, month, year, hour, minute));
```

Recycler view:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

        Context context;
        public MyAdapter(Context context){
            this.context = context;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tasklist,parent,false);
            return new MyViewHolder(view);

        }

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
            Button btnShowDone;
            TextView tvShowTask, tvShowDescription, tvShowTime, tvShowDate;

            public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
                super(itemView);

                tvShowTask = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTaskDisp);
                tvShowTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimeDisp);
                tvShowDate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDateDisp);
                tvShowDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescDisp);
                btnShowDone = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDone);

                btnShowDone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Delete Confirmation");
                        builder.setMessage("Are you sure this task is done ?");
                        builder.setCancelable(false);
                        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                deleteTask(taskRecord.get(getAdapterPosition()).getTask());
                                taskRecord.remove(taskRecord.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        });
                        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
            }
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

            String format;
            int hour = taskRecord.get(position).getHour();
            if (hour == 0) {
                hour += 12;
                format = "AM";
            } else if (hour == 12) {
                format = "PM";
            } else if (hour > 12) {
                hour -= 12;
                format = "PM";
            } else {
                format = "AM";
            }

            String minZero;
            int minute = taskRecord.get(position).getMinute();
            if (minute < 10){
                minZero = "0";
            } else if (minute > 10){
                minZero = "";
            }else {
                minZero = "";
            }

            holder.tvShowTask.setText("Task: " + taskRecord.get(position).getTask());
            String time = taskRecord.get(position).getHour() + ":" + minZero + taskRecord.get(position).getMinute() + " " + format;
            holder.tvShowTime.setText("Time: "+ time);
            String date = taskRecord.get(position).getDay() + " " + theMonth(taskRecord.get(position).getMonth()-1) + " " + taskRecord.get(position).getYear();
            holder.tvShowDate.setText("Date: "+ date);
            holder.tvShowDescription.setText("Description: " + taskRecord.get(position).getDescription());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return taskRecord.size();
        }
        public String theMonth(int month){
            String[] monthNames = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
            return monthNames[month];
        }

        public void deleteTask(String name){
            SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete("taskRecord", "task=?", new String[]{name});
            db.close();
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to sort your list before set data in adapter

```
ArrayList<Student> arraylist
            = new ArrayList<Student>();
        arraylist.add(new Student(12, "Robinson", 21));
        arraylist.add(new Student(14, "Mahi", 11));
        arraylist.add(new Student(13, "Jack", 31));
  
        Collections.sort(arraylist);
  
        for (Student str : arraylist) {
            System.out.println(str);
        }
```

after short the list then you set adapter data

```
adapter.setList(arraylist)
```